# *** glibc detected *** : free(): invalid next size (fast) in C code

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management

I am getting the the following error in a C code.

```
             *** glibc detected *** : free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

I have pasted code [here](http://codepaste.net/iccyk7)

Could anybody help me why i am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

```
  ** glibc detected *** ./bplus: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000077f1b0    ***
  ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib/libc.so.6(+0x775b6)[0x7fae8e5615b6]  
 /lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x73)[0x7fae8e567e83]
./bplus[0x401acf]
./bplus[0x401caf]
 /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fae8e508c4d]
./bplus[0x400669]
 ======= Memory map: ======== 
  00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 544621                             
  00602000-00603000 r--p 00002000 08:07 544621                             
  00603000-00604000 rw-p 00003000 08:07 544621                             
  0077f000-007a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
  7fae88000000-7fae88021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
  7fae88021000-7fae8c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
  7fae8e2d3000-7fae8e2e9000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 147                              /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
  7fae8e2e9000-7fae8e4e8000 ---p 00016000 08:07 147                          /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
  7fae8e4e8000-7fae8e4e9000 r--p 00015000 08:07 147                        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
  7fae8e4e9000-7fae8e4ea000 rw-p 00016000 08:07 147                        /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
  7fae8e4ea000-7fae8e664000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 943                        /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
  7fae8e664000-7fae8e863000 ---p 0017a000 08:07 943                        /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
  7fae8e863000-7fae8e867000 r--p 00179000 08:07 943                        /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
  7fae8e867000-7fae8e868000 rw-p 0017d000 08:07 943                        /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
  7fae8e868000-7fae8e86d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
  7fae8e86d000-7fae8e88d000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 488                        /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
  7fae8ea63000-7fae8ea66000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
  7fae8ea88000-7fae8ea8c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
  7fae8ea8c000-7fae8ea8d000 r--p 0001f000 08:07 488                        /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
  7fae8ea8d000-7fae8ea8e000 rw-p 00020000 08:07 488                        /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
  7fae8ea8e000-7fae8ea8f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
  7fff8d3c9000-7fff8d3de000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
  7fff8d3ff000-7fff8d400000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso] 
  ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
  Aborted
```

[EDIT 2]

For testing I am using `printf` in different regions. The program prints upto the
line which is just above  from the line where the `free` function called.

Comment: Please cut your code down to the *minimum* compilable example that still demonstrates the problem, and then paste it directly into your question.

Comment: Which of the calls to `free()` is causing the error?

Comment: i am not so sure about which free is causing error.

Comment: To discover which `free`, run your program in a debugger, or add `printf` statements to tell you where your program is going before it crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of code is likely contributing to the problem (beginning at line 62):

```
for (i =0 ; i < order ; i++) {  /*Stores the leaf key pointer pairs and new key pointer pairs in order form  in temp. storage*/
      if (i == InsertionIndex) {
           i =i+1;
      }
      temp_keys[i] = bplus_IndividualKeyBplus(bplusLeaf,j);
      temp_pointers[i] = bplus_IndividualPointersBplus(bplusLeaf,j);
      j = j+1;
}
```

If `InsertionIndex` is `order-1`, a pair of out-of-buffer writes occur.  Whatever immediately follows `temp_key` and `temp_pointers` is stomped upon, undoubted part of the heap used to manage other heap objects.

The construction itself is suspicious.  Review the intent of the code and fix.